# How can I make action bar tabs center align in Android?

Tags: android, android-actionbar

Android action bar tabs are left-aligned by default, I want to align it the center of the action bar. Is there any way we can make it center?

Comment: You can add this to xml layout `android:gravity="center"` or `android:layout_gravity="center"`

Comment: thanks but my tab action bar created using Actiobar.TabListener so there is no xml file.

Comment: A similar problem with a bad solution is here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8136754/how-to-align-the-actionbar-tabs-to-the-right

following that logic, you could get your screen size and dynamically add white space to each tab.

Comment: solution is right but I want  built action should be center. is there any way to do this ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was able to center-align the actionbar by customizing my application theme

In my AndroidManifest.xml, I added a android:theme property:

```
<application
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:theme="@style/CustomActionBarTheme">
  ...
```

I then added a new themes.xml file to my project, and added :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <!-- the theme applied to the application or activity -->
    <style name="CustomActionBarTheme"
           parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarTabBarStyle">@style/MyActionBarTabBar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="MyActionBarTabBar">
        <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

The tabs should now be center-aligned.

EDIT: 
It works only if your actionbar is displayed on 2 lines (in portrait)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [ViewPagerIndicator](http://viewpagerindicator.com/) plugin to customize your tabs.

Hope it helps!